# How can I solve the issue with amCharts line graph in IE

Tags: php, javascript, amcharts

I am doing a site in PHP which has a graphical presentation. I have used `amCharts`. I have drawn the graph. It works but the line displays strange, when I am using `IE browser` and it has no problem in Mozillla Firefox.   I have added the line graph in fiddle. Please check it. Any help will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/soumyamohanan/Qr7we/2/

Comment: The chart looks the same for me in all versions of IE.

Comment: please compare the graph with mozillla fire fox , in mozillla the line graph was connected but in Ie it displays as dots not connected.

Comment: Are you still having issues with this as it seems to work in both IE and Firefox from what I can see?